# How to replace an existing button in Action bar in Android with another button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to replace the button highlighted in the below image with another button that links to a webpage:

[image: replace highlighted button]

This is the code I have in the menu xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:visible="false"
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="?attr/ic_action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    android:icon="?attr/ic_action_refresh"/>
```

How to replace the highlighted button with another icon that's simply a hyperlink to another page?

Comment: The button you want to be replaced by another one is invisible in xml. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

do like below

```
 android:icon="@drawable/icon" // your drawable icon
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change icons like this : `android:icon="@drawable/ic_your_icon"` and add your logic to this method:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.your_item) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"); 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: Where to add the logic?

Comment: if (id == R.id.your_item) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"); 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }

Comment: I meant in which file to add this logic?

Comment: This method is situated in your activity which has action menu

Comment: Do I need to replace item with a unique name for the action or just write item as it is?

Comment: it is up to you